# Can AnkhSVN tell me when a solution needs updating?

Tags: visual-studio, ankhsvn

Sometimes I open a solution, make some change, compile, commit, deploy the software and only later realize that some colleague made a change that is not included in my build, since I forgot to "*Update to Latest Version*" first.

What I'd like is the following: *When opening a solution*, AnkhSVN should check whether my version is up-to-date and *recommend that I update* if it isn't.

I'd send a feature request, but since AnkhSVN has such a lot of features and this is such an *obviously useful* one (at least to me), I actually assume that this feature is already there and that I missed it when going through the AnhkSVN configuration options.

Is this feature there? If yes, how do I activate it?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is indeed already there. Go to View -> Pending Changes, then click on the clock symbol (Recent Changes). Here check the "Refresh every...." checkbox and select a timespan. Files that are changed on the server and are not updated yet are shown in this view now.